# I cant print ":" using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Whenever I am trying to print something that contains `:` symbol, jQuery triggers error

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :`

and when I try to print time, such as, `09:00`, It triggers

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: 00`

Why it happens? My Ajax call is

```
jQuery("#_dob").change(function() {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('deliverybydatepro/index/index') ?>",
                        data: "checkIn="+jQuery(this).val()+"&type=calendar",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data) {
                           var $response=jQuery(data);
                           jQuery("#div1").html(data);
                        }
                    });
    });
```

In second Second page, If i echoes something having `:`, i m getting the above errors.

Any idea?

Comment: try to send encoded response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you writing like `var $response=jQuery(data)`; ? if your response is 09:00 , it will be `jQuery("09:00")`. It will be problem.

I think , `var $response=jQuery(data);` is not require.

Your code should be

```
success: function(data) {
    jQuery("#div1").html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think there is a problem with your get request try it with post

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo get_admin_url() ?>admin-ajax.php',
          data: {  
              action: 'connection'
          },
```

Comment: But I m still getting above errors :(

Comment: Dont know why it happened. I started from the scratch again, and now its Ok. Thanks for your effort.